# GoogleApiClient is not configured to use Fitness.API required for this call

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to send history of one week Calories burnt data using History_API.
My code is like this -

```
// Connection Establishment
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {

}
```

I am getting this error "GoogleApiClient is not configured to use Fitness.API required for this call." Any idea why?

Comment: it's look like you forgot call `.addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)` in GoogleApiClient.Builder

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the Fitness.SENSORS_API when you initialize the mClient.

The code will look something like this:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .build();
```

You can get more info here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness

Comment: if (mClient == null) {
            mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(
                            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                @Override
                                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                    
                                    MyCode();
                                }